# How to avoid TSLing warning "Calls to '$' are not allowed. please don't"

Tags: angular, typescript, lint

I'm using cheerio and angular DataTables so I sometimes use $ to get raw strings from the HTML or add classes like this

```
$('td', row).addClass('highlight');

if ($('td', row).eq(3)[0].innerHTML === liqs[cIndex]) { ... }
```

Also I'm using it to send the tables to the printer

```
$(win.document.body).find('table')...
```

Is there a way to fix this or should I ignore the warning?

Comment: What was the exact wording of the warning?

Comment: Same as the title, it literally says file.ts[767, 33]: Calls to '$' are not allowed. please don't

Comment: Can you post your tslint.json please?

Comment: Can't since I get the 'post is mostly code' warning, but I see the problem now, I had $ banned at the tslint.json, thanks

Comment: you shouldn't be using jquery in your angular code

Comment: what should I use as an alternative?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve, but it's very much possible (and preferable) to build a complex Angular application without needing any jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably this is coming from the tslint [`ban` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ban/).  If you don't want to follow this rule, you can turn it off in `tslint.json` or use a `// tslint:disable-next-line` comment to suppress an individual warning.